# Connecting Pyspark to Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hive

I have a question about connecting Hive and Pyspark. I am using Mac by the way.
I have some data saved into Hive. I want to get the data from Hive by Pyspark and use it to run some queries.
Before, I simply got the data from the hive to Pycharm by making connections using Pyhive.

ex) conn = hive.Connection(host='101.50.123', port = 10000, username='abc123', password='***', database='dataset_1')

However, when I was trying to use pyspark to get the hive data, I was not sure which function to use. I have done some research, there were some functions such as enableHiveSupport() or spark.sql.warehouse.dir, but

Question is, where do I put my host, username, password, database in order to connect Pyspark to Hive? I have already tried to set the path of Hive, Haddop, Java, Spark ... but did not work either. I am completely new to pyspark that's why I am so confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Have already tried, but did not work"... Can you share your code and config files and the exact error you get? No, you shouldn't be using PyHive with Spark since that doesn't allow you to use the actual Spark cluster (only the driver will be running the query)

Comment: I get these errors when I type in hive into iterm:Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:610)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:553)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:750)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

Comment: sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Comment: @OneCricketeer I did not use pyhive for connecting Spark. 
This time I tried using spark built-in function to get the hive data. I also saw the link what thebluephantom said, but what I wanted to do was connect hive to spark by using my host, username, password and database.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code (and your hive-site.xml) and the formatted error. Did you follow the steps in the link from the error?